# Google adMob in Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) 2.0 without plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, ads, cordova-2.0.0

I am a mobile app developer, using the **Cordova** Framework. I want to integrate **Google adMob** in my projects without plugins. I want to use a simple Javascript code, because I will control better how and when to display ad banners on screen, in any operating systems: WP7, Android, iOS...

I found an old article (June 2011) that shows how do it. It uses [this javascript file](http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js), but it doesn't works. I am trying this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var admob_vars = {
  pubid: 'a1501b#######150', // publisher id
  bgcolor: 'FFFFFF', // background color (hex)
  text: '000000', // font-color (hex)
  test: true // test mode, set to false to receive live ads
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js">
</script> 
<div style="position:absolute; z-index:999999; left:1px; top:100px; width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#e0e0e0; color:Blue;">
  [Google Ads div]
  <div id="admob_ad"></div>
</div>
<script>
    _admob.fetchAd(document.getElementById('admob_ad'));
</script>
```

Alternatively, I'd like to find a mobile ads agency that allows the use of Javascript files in my app mobile projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I was trying to use the same javascript code. But it seems Google has withdrawn it's support for this method as mentioned [here](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704625)

Following is an excerpt from the page:

> Please note that we are closing down AdMob Smartphone Web on May 1, 2012 and consolidating it with the main Google AdSense for content product.

[This](http://therockncoder.blogspot.in/2012/08/jquery-mobile-and-adsense.html) site will help to integrate adsense in Cordova. But it has it's limitations. **Jquery mobile's ajax transitions are to be turned off for adsense to work!**

So I'll be sticking with the Admob SDK till a better solution pops up.

Hope it helps.

#### Edit:

Today I came across [InMobi ad network](http://www.inmobi.com) which support fetching ads through javascript. The JS code is [here](http://www.inmobi.com/developer/platforms/mobile-web/#clientjava).
Whereas InMobi's official comparison with Admob is [here](http://www.inmobi.com/inmobiblog/2011/01/24/the-inmobi-network-versus-the-google-admob-network-see-how-we-stack-up/).
So far I have not come across any ad mediation support by the InMobi network. But I guess I'll give it a try.

Comment: I fear this answer is not applicable because Cordova applications are written in HTML5+CSS+JS like as a web site, but is not a web site. The [adMod link](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1704625) alerts that the "Smartphone web" are closing down. Is it right?

Comment: @riofly yeah it is not a website. But for the ads server, our app acts like a website. Since the "Smartphone Web" is closed down, we cannot run the [javascript file](http://mmv.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js) in our apps anymore.

Comment: Ok, I was try inMobi. It works fine, and I can decide runtime when and where ad will be show.

Answer (score 0):

I did a blog post which explains how to integrate AdMob into a Cordova app: [AdMob and Cordova](http://therockncoder.blogspot.in/2012/05/cordova-phonegap-and-admob-together-ios.html).